# Getting an error while merging two data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge two data frames to perform some analysis, however when I try I get an error on the key I am trying to join on indicating it has duplicates and also about the dtypes.

However I did change the dtpes to match before the merging and I also check for any duplicates on the filed I am trying to join and there are no duplicates.

This is the first dataframe :

```
data_edw.dtypes

cntry_enti_nbr      int64
Total_IPF           int64
Total_IEF           int64
Total_Volume        int64
Total_Weight      float64
dtype: object
```

This is the second dataframe:

```
data_oracle.dtypes 

CNTRY_ENTI_NBR           int64
TR_CURR_IPF_VOL_PCT    float64
TR_CURR_IEF_VOL_PCT    float64
dtype: object
```

The merge logic

```
d1 = data_edw.merge(data_oracle, on='cntry_enti_nbr', how ='left')
```

The error is as below

```
1381         # Check for duplicates
```

KeyError: 'cntry_enti_nbr'

I even checked for duplicates on the column but there are none

```
data_edw['cntry_enti_nbr'].duplicated().any()

False
```

Comment: Did you check duplicates for both dataframes ? Also try keeping consistent column names either lowercase or uppercase.

Comment: if you see the case, its `CNTRY_ENTI_NBR` not `cntry_enti_nbr`

Comment: it seems the mismatching uppercase and lowercase. If you can't change the column names to all lowercase, you need to specify `left_on` and `right_on` with exact cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cntry_enti_nbr in the second dataframe is on upper case try changing it to lower case

```
data_oracle.rename(columns={'CNTRY_ENTI_NBR':'cntry_enti_nbr'}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you @nassim it worked !